# How do I clear a table with a lot of references in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, foreign-keys

For instance, suppose I have table A.  Then I have tables B-Z that have a foreign key to table A's primary key.  Then perhaps there are also some tables that have a foreign key constraint to a table in B-Z's primary key constraint.  Is there any easy way to clear out table A and all of the tables that refer to A (or that refer to a table that refers to A) without having to explicitly delete from each table or add an ON CASCADE constraint to each foreign key?

Note that this is mainly for testing purposes, not to be used in production.  I would just drop the entire schema and start over again, but that simply isn't feasible for every test (considering how long it takes to build the schema).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a CASCADE?

Comment: Wouldn't I have to add CASCADE to every foreign key?  Honestly, if I'm going to take that approach, why would I not just delete from every table instead?

Comment: Why don't you just delete from every table instead, though?

Comment: Could you restore from a backup of an empty DB with your schema already in place?

Comment: @Rob, that's what I'm doing right now. I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to do it.  :-)

Comment: > Wouldn't I have to add CASCADE to
> every foreign key? Honestly, if I'm
> going to take that approach, why would
> I not just delete from every table
> instead?
Well, you would only change the foreign keys once, or rather their generating script.

Comment: @jhartelt - This is indeed true, and it's a good point.  As it stands right now though, my automated tests will clear every table programmatically, so this isn't a concern.  My main concern is the maintenence cost of having to update the list of tables to be cleared every time our schema changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way to do this would be to drop all the FK's, truncate the tables, and then rebuild the FK's.

Comment: He won't be able to recreate all the FKs until the specific rows out of the child tables have been fixed, though.  I think he only wants to remove some of the rows out of the child tables.

Comment: I was basing my answer on the phrase "clear out table A and all of the tables that refer to A (or that refer to a table that refers to A)", which I assume meant that the child tables should be completely emptied as well.